# XeLaTeX and unicode-math problems

Tags: fonts, xetex, texlive, unicode-math

I am using XeLaTeX (TeXLive 2011) on OS X. It seems that unicode-math is not working as it should:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
```

Produces:

```
kpathsea: Invalid fontname `XITS Math/ICU', contains ' '
```

Same error occurs with Asana Math and Neo Euler.

Comment: Does it work if you use `xits-math.otf` instead of `XITS Math`?

Comment: That probably means that the font can't be found. Does it work with LuaLaTeX? Does it work with `xits-math.otf` as font name?

Comment: Not the first time: a question that exactly states the problem I have, but is closed as "too localized".